# Keeping Survey Data Anonymous

Tags: powerbi, powerpivot, dax

We have been conducting a survey within our business and I will shortly be preparing the results to share with a number of internal customers.

The number of survey respondents is around 700, so I want to allow the people looking at the reports to be able to filter the data to identify trends according to the demographic and organisational groups identified within the report (sample data below).

[image]

What I am looking to do is present the information in a way that prevents the users from using a combination of the slicers to identify the responses of specific individuals.

I wanted to obscure the results for cases where the group of people selected is less than 5 individuals and created the following measure:

> [Anonymised Rowcount]:=if(COUNTROWS(('Table1'))<5,0,[RowCount])

However the results it gives aren't quite what I need:
I **want** all the values of [Anonymised Rowcount] to be zero when the combination of slicers gives me less than 5 active rows in the table.
I'm **getting** a zero in any columns when the count for that column falls below 5.

[image: Chart showing incorrect behaviour]
*NOT the desired result!*

I've tried various combinations of *ALL()* and *ALLSELECTED()*, but I've not yet managed to come up with a correct combination the will give me a count of the rows in the table that ignores the column, but respects the slicer selections. My attempts so far have either given me every row in the table, ignoring the columns and slicers, or only the selected rows within each column heading.

**EDIT**:

## Main question resolved

I've found the Solution using:

> [Anonymised Rowcount]:=if(COUNTROWS(ALL('Table 1'[Question 1]))<5,0,[RowCount])

**Bonus Question**: Does anyone have a more elegant way of obscuring the results of small groups than just setting all the responses to zero.

Comment: You can post your answer as an answer so that it doesn't continue to be flagged as unanswered. (Plus it's a useful answer!) One tangential thought...if you're sharing this in Excel, it's not impossible for someone to go into the Power Pivot window to see all the underlying data (or to create their own separate pivot table on the data), even as you zero out the measure on your pivot chart.